# Typescript type narrowing based on class instance

Tags: typescript

I have `Person` class which implements interface `IPerson`. The interface were to have two variants: `IPerson1` | `IPerson2`

```js
interface IPerson {
    name: string | "all",
    age?: number,
    height?: number,
    population?: number,
}

interface IPerson1 {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    height: number,
}
interface IPerson2 {
    name: "all",
    population: number
}

class Person implements IPerson {
    name: string;
    age?: number|undefined;
    height?: number|undefined;
    population?: number|undefined;
    constructor(name: "all", population: number);
    constructor(name: string, age: number, height: number);
    constructor(name: string, ageOrPopulation: number, height?: number) {
        this.name = name;
        if (height) {
            this.age = ageOrPopulation;
            this.height = height;
        } else {
            this.population = ageOrPopulation;
        }
    }
}

new Person("all", 3e6).population // I hope here population is number instead of number | undefined
// I hope Person can implement both interface IPerson1 and IPerson2, and typescript can do type narrowing for me.
```

It's worth to mention,  in my real code, `Person` class has so many methods, so I have to use `class` for good code structuring.

Is there any workaround for this scenario? Seems like if `class` can implments `type`, then I can make it implement a union type so TS can do type narrowing for me.  [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAsAFDLnIhwC2EAXMlmFKAObIA%20yARHADZ9uAGlIVkcVhAD8DEAFdqAI2giyFABYRgrdWBmUFyqKrEAHHKbl84YYHn3ylK0gF9SpUJFiIUGbHgBGQlEKKloGJhYQVhMKCXoDJ2MQ8k1tXVlDZxI3Ek9oeCQ0TChcEAAmYLVyMITeAWEU5HNLa1s8TKTXdxIEaywsZBKy5GBqUz4IWnBBv1K8KrFaiOY2AG4m%20IcsqA45EAATCBhQCAON6uQ0nT1Ooz3D49PzpparGzsQbaSHo5OQM4XMQIPCROQIMA4KAACmWPH4giEzQs73aIDu0AAlECKCCQGCIVDYTQEpE2Ej4hjjFctDcqdimniCZCYXCydEKZIAPJQdAotqfKlI666b5GTGLMQUMDqYBYAB0tWQAF5KCScVLRjBkNCRWAJcRLpryDK5fL4irxNzefyPngNcaTbKFXrLXqHWIXMgIHwsChDY6xKaFW8BQtVfEeXzWnaQB6KLlPd0SKQAQB3Ib%20EDQ%20qI5AAZggADZMfLQ7HkAB6StoK4WFCaKAocto0aDRxGUb4yBwA7IHDajvQTjIfZ-Z6kauMCBTQZ8YAAaxQwwWCDg%20DGEymEBmyEUOBlXa8hV8K5AQXXfbmZXKFMOyDAAE9TBAsAgWKYwMg1-gDjgH8%20KBUFAUA4GmbDIDAULILQ8pAA)

Comment: This doesn't look like it should be a single class. I'd assume that in many of your many methods you'll also have to make a distinction between `IPerson1` and `IPerson2`. Then why even putting them together? Use two separate classes and maybe a base-class with shared methods/code.

Comment: `population` is an [Optional Property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) in the interface and in the class, and that means an `undefined` is implicit in the `type`.

Comment: You could create a custom annotation for the ctor function, but you can't do it directly on the constructor. Not sure if the pattern you are trying to use is the best though.

Comment: Annotating the class separately  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeyIcAthAFzJZhSgDmANMnPRAPxUgCupARtGYALCMHpCwnYrwFRmABxzzuAGzhhgeKT36DkAXwBQoSLEQoM2PACZCxMpWQAiOCpVOFS1es0guM6ANDQwQ1LCxkTChcfGBSeRUIcnAIy2i8QkNkbJY2bQCoAB9uEAATCBhQCFKAbiyckTEJfN0ikvLKkGq6nORFZTUNLX9W4rKKqtr67IQ8GihuBDAcKAAKZT4VYAR7cip5hmZWCAB5KHQvQd8R2WFRcUkb6ABKTN7egHovgDpf6aCjLMQDRIlYQABhZZQZAAXlB6XwcAiBH+XQA7shViQ9s5XO5PAMfHgnlBnlQ0jFrKiIBisQ59rRDrlHDpbshGg8SWS0FEYoZ9Mhguj4TFIStVi43B5kABmCAANme3363iG+C+aHZShQIigKBVVwywAirMCoBoEDgpWQOBg0layEKyHaEy6pUMQA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks, may u expand your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Thomas Agree, I will refactor it, but currently I'm gonna stick to this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't  directly annotate the type of a constructor. You can however change the type of the class my assigning it to another variable and asserting a different type. With this technique you can then have different constructor signatures returning different types:

```
interface IPerson { name: string, age?: number, height?: number, population?: number, }
interface IPerson2 { name: "all", population: number }

class Person implements IPerson {
    age?: number|undefined;
    height?: number|undefined;
    population?: number|undefined;
    constructor(public name: string, ageOrPopulation: number, height?: number) {
        ///...
    }
}
const PersonCtor = Person as {
    new (name: "all", population: number): IPerson2
    new (name: string, age: number, height: number): IPerson
} 

new PersonCtor("all", 3e6).population // I hope here population is number instead of number | undefined
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeyIcAthAFzJZhSgDmANMnPRAPxUgCupARtGYALCMHpCwnYrwFRmABxzzuAGzhhgeKT36DkAXwBQoSLEQoM2PACZCxMpWQAiOCpVOFS1es0guM6ANDQwQ1LCxkTChcfGBSeRUIcnAIy2i8QkNkbJY2bQCoAB9uEAATCBhQCFKAbiyckTEJfN0ikvLKkGq6nORFZTUNLX9W4rKKqtr67IQ8GihuBDAcKAAKZT4VYAR7cip5hmZWCAB5KHQvQd8R2WFRcUkb6ABKTN7egHovgDpf6aCjLMQDRIlYQABhZZQZAAXlB6XwcAiBH+XQA7shViQ9s5XO5PAMfHgnlBnlQ0jFrKiIBisQ59rRDrlHDpbshGg8SWS0FEYoZ9Mhguj4TFIStVi43B5kABmCAANme3363iG+C+aHZShQIigKBVVwywAirMCoBoEDgpWQOBg0layEKyHaEy6pUMQA)